# DBfit - comparing 2 tables actual and expected

Tags: fitnesse, dbfit

i am writing tests using DbFit and FitNesse for some our reporting stored procedures. To make  life easy, we have designed a generic way to store input data and expected data in 2 tables and comparing the output table with the expected table, for each and every case.
i failed to do so, as DbFit is only expecting the actual value to be hardcoded in the page.

Comment: What are you trying to do? a) Compare the data within two tables against each other for differences,or b) Check the data output from a stored proc always matches your expected output recorded in the fitnesse wiki?

Comment: option b - Check the data output from a stored proc always matches your expected output recorded in the fitnesse wiki

Comment: Could you please illustrate the type of test that you wish to write with an example?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, DbFit compares to the expected values on the wiki page, not the values in another table.  To compare values in 2 tables will require writing a new fixture.